# The state of Shamir's Secret Sharing in 2023

Tags: secret-sharing, passwords

Shamir's Secret Sharing GPL implementation called `ssss` got removed from Tails OS years back.

- Is Shamir's secret sharing still secure nowadays? Why was it removed from Tails OS?
- Is it true that the technical limit is a maximum of 128 characters?

Comment: What do you call "technical limit"?

Comment: If, by technical limit, you mean something inherent within Shamir's Secret Sharing protocol, no, there isn't; it can share arbitrarily large secrets.  If you mean something inherent within the `ssss` implementation, well, there might be...

Comment: @levgeni a hard limit programmed into `ssss`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Tails 3.14 announcement](https://tails.net/news/version_3.14/) list `ssss` as one of a dozen applications removed in that version, and then says

> You can install these applications again using the Additional Software feature.
>
> Thanks to the removal of these less popular applications in 3.14 and the removal of some language packs in 3.13.2, Tails 3.14 is 39 MB smaller than 3.13.

So it appears to me that `ssss` was removed only because it wasn't widely used, and it is still available, just not installed by default.

Shamir secret sharing is as secure as it ever was. See [this answer](/a/107715) by fgrieu for a summary. I can't vouch for `ssss`'s implementation of it.

There is no limit on the length of the secret, but specific implementations like `ssss` may have limits.